# UITabBar height difference in iOS15 Beta 5

Tags: objective-c, height, uitabbar, ios14, ios15

Currently profiling App changes for the up-and-coming release of iOS15.

iPad App using Objective-C.

I have Xcode 13 Beta 5. First UI differences I'm hit with are the Tab Bar height and that it is transparent.

It appears to be larger than it's previous iOS counterparts? Guessing there's no way to shorten it - break iOS15 UI guidelines and wot-not.

I'm not using auto-layout and UI components are explicitly placed. This is quite a problem. Also, the status bar is now transparent as is the navigation-bar. At the moment, it's making for less screen real-estate in terms of height. Tab Bar is bigger.

Anyone seen this or have a solution?